# Batch File for Searching a Directory and Deleting specific Folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file, file-management

I need to have a batch file or powershell script that will search a given directory when ran and delete any folders (and their files) that are inside that directory.

For Example:  I am trying to delete folder called 'AppStore' that is located at C:\Users\Jeff\ AND also located at C:\Users\Jim AND c:\Users\Bob .  So, I need to be able to delete the folder and corresponding files associated with the directorty in any folder under C:Users\ .

Thanks.

I have tried to write a batch file but I can only get it to delete the folders IF I know the exact path.  And being as I would run this on multiple machines the path would change.

Comment: You're almost certainly not going to have access to Jeff's _and_ Jim's _and_ Bob's user folders from just Jeff's account. Will using `%userprofile%` suffice so that each of the three users can check their own paths without needing to update the code of the script, or do you still need to recursively check `C:\Users`?

Comment: This file would be pushed out to the machines (using PDQ to push the batch file and run with provided credentials) and run with local admin privileges so access wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell and its [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) cmdlet (as noted, you'll need to run *with elevation*):

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force C:\Users\*\AppStore -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>